# How can i refresh the current date inside a running Python process?

Tags: python, server, cron, telegram-bot, supervisord

I'm using `supervisord` to keep a Telegram bot developed with Python running on a server and I'm using the datetime library to get the current date and perform an operation that depends on the current date.

```
from datetime import date


today = date.today()
```

The problem: I noticed that, when the process is running, the Python always returns the same date; so, my bot doesn't return a different output each day, but the same.

To solve that, I had to enter the server, stop supervisor, kill the process and, manually, execute the python script to run the bot with the current date.

I thought about using a crontab to run `supervisorctl restart all` one time per day, but when i run that command the Python process doesn't stopped, even when I killed the process and run that command the output still returned the date of yesterday, I needed to manually run `python3 myfile.py` to refresh it. There is a way that I can actualize the Python date.today() without killing the process, or a way that I can kill and restart the Python process refreshing the current date?

The current code:

```
def get_today_meditation(update, context):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    today = date.today()
    print(today)
    [ ... ]


def main():
    key_api = os.environ.get('PYTHON_API_BREVIARIO_KEY')
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "pt_BR.UTF-8")
    updater = Updater(key_api, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('meditacaodehoje', get_today_meditation))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Comment: maybe you should run `date.today()` in different place - in place where you really need current date. If you run it only once at start then you will have always the same value.

Comment: @furas i run the date.today() whenever the telegram bot is called, but the telegram bot "listener" is always the same process, i think this causes the problem

Comment: `date.today()` should always gives correct current date. But if you use
`today = date.today()` at start and later you will use `today` then you will get always the same value. Listener has nothing to do with this.

Comment: i always replace the today variable in this case. everytime that the bot is called i call the function that calls date.today(), but the python process is always the same.

Comment: I can't see your code so I can't explain why it doesn't give correct date. At this moment the only idea is that you call function which should use `date.today()` to get new value but it gets old value from `today`. But without code this problem can't be explain. Other idea: if you runs it on external server then it may runs in different time zone and it may have new day few hour later then you.

Comment: @furas Sorry, i edited and added the current code

Comment: I can't run it but inside `get_today_meditation` you assign `date.today()` to `local` variable `today` but it doesn't update `global` variable `today` - so if you use in other function value from global variable `today` then it will be incorrect. And it would need line `global today` inside `get_today_meditation` to assign value to global variable